# Tips on reducing Polycount in Scene

Tags: performance

I have a problem. There is a lot of figures I created for an art project in my school.

I used UV Spheres as models and smooth shaded them. In the end I had 35 million vertices and as you can see around 28 gb in memory. I tried to reduce vertices with a decimate modifier. Now its 176000 vertices but Blender is still super slow in reaction times. It needs half a minute to select a model. And I cant seem to find a way to apply these decimate modifiers to all models in the scene at once.

I used ctrl + l to apply modifiers but cant "apply" them in second step.

Any advice would be appreciated.

[image: n]

Comment: This is probably caused by a lot of calculations multiple Decimate modifiers are doing. It looks like in 2.8 you press Ctrl+A in Object mode and then choose to apply modifiers. Other than that this is the same as it was in 2.79

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you can try:

1. Select one object and add the decimate modifier. Do not apply it.
2. Select all objects EXCEPT for the one with the modifier.
3. Shift-select the modified object. It will now be the active object
       (bright yellow-orange outline).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and choose "Modifiers" from the Make Links menu.

This should apply the modifier across all objects and keep the modifier editable.

Alternatively, you could apply the modifier in the first step and in the fourth step select "Object Data". Keep in mind this links the objects so certain changes made to the active object will take effect across all the others. Scaling and other transforms done in Object Mode should not affect the others.

If you need to unlink object data the method in 2.8 is select one object in Object Mode and in the Object menu (top left of the viewport) select Object> Relations> Make Single User> Object & Data (or whatever serves your purpose) and select All.

In 2.79 and earlier select an object, hit <kbd>U</kbd>, and choose Object & Data or whatever.